# Does a navigation menu belong in the HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigationbar

Up to this point, I have been putting all of my navigation menu bars (horizontal, at the top of the screen) in a `<section>` inside the HTML file. However, I recently came across an example where the navigation menu was created by using JavaScript to insert the necessary code into a specific `<section>` in the HTML file.

This caused me to wonder which method is most efficient, and why. To me, the JavaScript method ensures that you do not need to update each page individually when a change is made to the navigation bar. However, are there any negative side-effects to using JavaScript (besides the possibility of JavaScript being disabled in the broswer)?

Comment: Well if you do not use serverside code to include it, it is a way to add it to every page without having to edit it in multiple locaitons. JS disabled means no navigation.

Comment: Javascript can be disabled in a browser (like mine is for most sites) therefore crippling your main navigation. With something as important as your main nav you probably want to render it without javascript. You can then use javascript to effect the main nav after load.

Comment: Also, it may affect [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

Comment: If you can do it in html and you don't need any JS features in the menu I'd keep it simple.

Comment: you should use both because relying on just one comes with lots of potential drawbacks. that said, who cares if no-js can't get to pages that don't do anything good in no-js anyway. unless it's a brochure site, js is pretty important to a good user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a server side script (like PHP) you can also include it in every page without too much effort.

Personally I would do in the HTML. I think a site that could work without JavaScript should work without JavaScript. Of course you can add scripts to make it work better, nicer and more efficient, but a plain navigation menu could work very well without JavaScript too.

Also note that not all web crawlers will be able to run your script, so they may not be able to follow the links in your menu. Of course this can also be solved by adding special site maps for crawlers, but then you're just making it harder.

So: As much 'plain' HTML with real links as possible. Add scripts to enhance user experience.

Comment: In the case of a user disabling JavaScript in their browser, what will happen to a drop-down menu system? Is that where a site map would be used?

Comment: You can make drop down menus without JavaScript, or make a [big menu](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/mega-menus/) that is transformed to a dropdown menu using JavaScript. That's what I meant with enhancing user experience. On the other hand, if an element doesn't work at all without JavaScript, it shouldn't be visible without JavaScript.